# Selecting DataGridRow Selected column - WPF c#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have two ComboBox columns in my DataGrid. I want to change ItemSource of second ComboBox cell when first ComboBox's value changes in selected row, only.
For now I am doing it like this:

```xml
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn 
        x:Name="ComboBx_Method"
        ElementStyle = "{StaticResource S1_DG_ComboBx_Element}"
        Header ="Payment Method" 
        SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Method, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
        Width="3*">
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>  
            <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource S1_DG_ComboBx_Element}" 
                   TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                <EventSetter Event="SelectionChanged" 
                             Handler="ComboBoxTest_SelectionChanged"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn 
        x:Name="ComboBx_Gateway"     
        ElementStyle="{StaticResource S1_DG_ComboBx_Element}" 
        EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource S1_DG_ComboBx_EditingElement}"  
        Header="Payment Gateway" 
        SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Gateway, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
        Width="3*"/> 
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Code Behind:

```cs
private void ComboBoxTest_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)DataGrid_PaymentTable
        .ItemContainerGenerator
        .ContainerFromIndex(DataGrid_PaymentTable.SelectedIndex);
}
```

Now I want to get second cell of selected row and change its itemsource property i.e row['ComboBox_gateway'].itemSource;
Is this possible?

**Update**
For now I didn't find any solutions, so I merged two columns information into one column. I made this control for arranging my data:
[Custom ComboBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StC7p.png)

Comment: I tried :
 DataRowView row = (DataRowView)DataGrid_PaymentTable.SelectedItems[0];
 MessageBox.Show(row["ComboBx_Gateway"].ToString());
But I am getting cast exception

Comment: Not quite clear.
The SelectionChanged event will fire on a specific cell in the Column.
And you want to change the source of the entire second column, that is, in all its cells.
That is, the source will be the same as specified in the last modified cell of the first column.
Changes from the previous cells (in the same column) will be lost.
Do you really need this kind of weird logic?

Comment: I just want to change the Itemsource of selected Row second column, not all of them.
Is this not possible? if not then I will try some alternative.

Comment: For a ComboBox in a different column of the same row?
If yes, then this should be done at the level of the collection element with which the row is associated, and not at the level of the DataGrid column.
Column DataGrid refers to all elements of the collection, not to any specific one.

Comment: Doing this at collection level will cause another problem (off topic). I think I should make a User Control and do it like this  [link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_optgroup).
Thanks for helping

Comment: The link is some HTML not related to WPF.
You are misunderstanding and using WPF.
You are thinking, "How can I do something with the data in the GUI?"
But there is no data in the GUI, there is only a representation of it.
All work with data occurs at their level (in this case, at the level of a collection item), and the GUI only provides a means of user interaction with this data.

Comment: For a normal description of your task, you need to add: the type of collection items and the collection itself used for the DataGrid, what collection you use for the ComboBox source in the first column, how the elements of this collection are related to the source for the ComboBox of the second column.
In theory, this should be a list of valid values ​​for the Gateway property.
How does the Method property relate to this list.
Without these details, it is almost impossible to answer your question.

Comment: @EldHasp, I know this is an HTML link,, i got inspiration from this for rearranging my data in WPF. In my view model, I am using an collection for datagrid. Basically, what my intention was following:
First column is Payment Method and Second Column is Payment Gateway,
when user selects a payment method, all gateways related to that method should appear in second column. I was asking if it is possible to change item source of column in single row bcz each row has its unique payment method selected, so only its rlatd gateway should be visible on second column. Control Img in question's update

Comment: From the XAML, this `Method` property of the row element should modify the collection on the second row.
It is not clear from your XAML the type of this property and the dependence the collection  of the Payment Gateways on its value.

Comment: You can change the source, but if the column type is DataGridTemplateColumn.
And this dependency will be set in the template of the column element.
I cannot say how, specifically, to implement this, since your question is not detailed enough.

Comment: Yesterday, I urgently needed solution (didn't got one) so I ended up with alternative and made a custom control, I put its Img in question's update. I need to complete this project in few days, so for now I will continue with alternative and I will change Interface   in future update, if I get any error.
But still,
Thanks! bcz of your comment, I stop waiting for answer from SO and move to alternative and that saved me lot of time